# Cloudkit : FetchUserRecordIdWithCompletionHandler returns previous user id

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, icloud, cloudkit

I have a problem with fetchUserRecordIdWithCompletionHandler when I logout of my Icloud account and sign in with another account and  return to my app. And I fetch the users record Id again to update the data, then it fetches the previous id from the user that signed out and not the id of the new user. I presume that cloudkit is caching the user id and it doesn't update it when the user signs out and signs in with another id.

However when the app is terminated and opened again it does recognise the new id.

Anyone know how to solve this problem or is this a bug.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you implement the following to capture login changes? was it called?         NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserverForName(NSUbiquityIdentityDidChangeNotification, object: nil, queue: nil) { _ in

Comment: Yes I did, and it gets called when the change happens but when I try to fetch the new id it keeps returning the old one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was solved after updating XCode to 7.1!

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this and it's fixed in at least iOS 9.2 but might have been earlier. I will update this post when I find out.

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[CKContainer defaultContainer] fetchUserRecordIDWithCompletionHandler:^(CKRecordID * _Nullable recordID, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if(error){
            NSLog(@"error fetching user record");
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"user %@", recordID);
    }];
}
```